# Why are electromagnetic waves sinusoidial?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I was [playing here in manual mode.](https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/radiating-charge/radiating-charge_en.html)The 'distortions' or newly formed electric field lines came in various shapes.Then, how come all electromagnetic waves are sine waves?

Comment: Keep in mind that the sinusoid that you see plotted is not the "shape" of a field line, it is the time and space dependence of the field strength. You should not be imagining wiggling field lines.

Comment: There is a good answer to your question here https://www.quora.com/Are-electromagnetic-waves-always-pure-sinusoids-And-if-so-why  but you might find a duplicate on this site.  I hope you get an answer here, but please remember that waves that you see in a lake when you throw a stone in, are not the same as mathematical descriptions of EM effects, they are to be viewed as analogies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not. It's just that sine waves are simpler than others and are representative of any other waves (in uniform space, for linear electrodynamics), as any other waves can be expressed as superpositions of sine waves.

Comment: Well ... If you solve the wave equation from Maxwell's theory indeed the solution of EM waves, sinusoidal. In practice there is nonlinear distortion, other effects that make 'measured' EM waves not necessarily sinusoidal.

Comment: @docscience The free-space wave equation that arises from Maxwell's equations is non-dispersive, so while we focus on the harmonic solutions as a basis for all solutions the general solution can have any continuous form consistent with the usual Fourier uncertainty relation.

Comment: @dmckee : Could you please explain? Either I don't understand your statement or I don't understand why non-dispersiveness (rather than linearity) is important for your statement.

Comment: Linearity is also important, of course, but when the layman thinks about waves they think about a shape moving along. Non-dispersiveness is necessary for a arbitrary combination of harmonic waves to preserve their shape as they move. Without that the harmonic solutions would be special in that way (though the linear combinations would still be valid solutions). In retrospect that comment was for too terse to convey what I meant. I hope this one helps a little.

Comment: @dmckee: In 3D, non-dispersiveness is necessary but not sufficient for an arbitrary combination of harmonic waves to preserve its shape. Furthermore, it is not sufficient even in 1 dimension (as waves can move in 2 directions), so the harmonic solutions are somewhat special in this respect anyway and maybe the uniformity and linearity conditions are enough for the discussion.